# I can't login to linux after uninstalling zsh

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

I installed zsh but faced some problems with it so i uninstalled it but forgot to switch shells and logged out, now im stuck on login loop

*I'm new to linux*

Comment: This should be useful: https://trendoceans.com/how-to-fix-login-issue-after-removing-zsh-from-debian-ubuntu/

Comment: Do you access the machine physically or via SSH or by some other means?

Answer (score 0):

- assuming you had your login account as zsh, and assuming you did not set up autologin, at the login screen choose the *root* account to log in to, which *should* still be `/bin/bash` for its shell; also assuming that the root account login is not disabled (like I see is now happening in centos9)
- boot linux to single user mode, that's where when the grub menu comes up at the very beginning of the boot process and has like a 7 second or less timeout you press any keyboard key to interrupt.  Then you can edit the underlying menu option and inject  *boot into single user mode* syntax.  That syntax will vary a little based on your linux distribution you are running, it's probably easiest to google *how do I boot (centos/debian/mint) into single user mode*.  You can also inject a `init=/bin/bash` syntax as well, then get into `/etc/passwd` and undo the zsh stuff.  Other option is boot via install linux install dvd to get into a rescue shell in order to edit `/etc/passwd` to undo zsh.